# Hybrid P2P's server data directory

Tags: dictionary, p2p, hybrid

I'm developing a some sort like P2P system here.
The types of P2P network that I'm going to use is Hybrid P2P.
But, there's a problem here which I don't know how to solve. 
It's the data directory.
How does the data directory works?
How does it knows that which nodes contain what files?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are referring to indexing resources available on your P2P network. Basically, a central peer stores which electronic resource is available on which peer.

Instead of querying all peers, a given peer can query the central peer containing the index. Then, this information can be used to fetch the electronic resource (PDF file, music, video, etc....) from the correct peer. It reduces traffic.